# how to do three class classification in R

Tags: r, classification, regression, cross-validation

I have 3  files representing three class ie Class 0, Class1 and Class2.
I wanted to read those 3 text files and want to do three class classification.
Is there a way I could read all the text files and combine them to a single file. and then create partition for classification?

My base code is

```
 basefile1 = read.table("data1.txt", header = TRUE)
 basefile2 = read.table("data2.txt", header = TRUE)
```

(How can I merge  these files before partitioning into 75% and 25% training testing set?

I need help in spliting the base files as its not just class 0 and class 1.
My initial code for 2 class was :

```
require(caret)
splitIndex <- createDataPartition(totalbasefile$CLASS, p = .75, list = FALSE, times = 1)
trainDF <- totalbasefile[ splitIndex,]
testDF  <- totalbasefile[-splitIndex,]
fsModels <- c("gbm", "lasso")
myFS<-fscaret(trainDF, testDF, myTimeLimit = 40, preprocessData=TRUE,
              Used.funcRegPred = 'gbm', with.labels=TRUE,
              supress.output=FALSE, no.cores=2)
```

What should I MODIFY for it to do 3 class classification in R?
Any suggestions will be helpful

Comment: Can you give us any information about how many columns the files `data1.txt` and `data2.txt` have?  If the two files have the same structure (i.e. number and name of columns), then you could `rbind()` `basefile1` and `basefile2` together.

Comment: Do you want to merge per `merge()` or do you want to use `rbind()` ?  
(relating your question about `basefile1` and `basefile2`)

Comment: for the first part: `do.call("rbind", lapply(filenames, read.table, header = TRUE))`